# Rotation of Orthonormal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I am self studying linear algebra at the moment and while trying to understand orthogonality I came up with the following question.

On the one hand, let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with an inner product which allows the existence of an orthonormal basis. Now let $v_{1}, ..., v_{n}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$, then for every two vectors $v,u\in V$ we have that
$$
<v,u>\ =\ <\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{i}v_{i},\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{j}v_{j}>\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n
\alpha_{i}\beta_{j}<v_{i}, v_{j}>\ =\ \sum_{j=1}^n
\alpha_{j}\beta_{j}\ =\ v_c \cdot u_c
$$
being $v_c$ and $u_c$ the coordinate vectors of $v$ and $u$ with respect to our basis.

On the other hand let $e_1$, $e_2$ represent the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and let $R(\theta)$ be a rotation by an angle $\theta$ i.e.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
cos\ \theta & -sin\ \theta \\
sin\ \theta & cos\ \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I say the set $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to be a rotation of the canonical basis if $v_1=R(\theta)e_1$ and $v_2=R(\theta)e_2$ for a given $\theta$. Using this definition one can see that the set of orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^2$ equals the set of rotations of the canonical basis.

With these two results in mind, let $V$ be a 2 dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ with an inner product and an orthonormal basis $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$, I say the set $\{w_1, w_2\}$ to be a rotation of $B$ if $(w_1)_c=R(\theta)(v_1)_c$ and $(w_2)_c=R(\theta)(v_2)_c$ for a given $\theta$, $u_c$ being the coordinate vector of $u$ with respect to $B$. Given that the product of any two vectors of this space can be treated as the dot product of coordinate vectors with real coefficients we can conclude that $\{v_1', v_2'\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ if and only if it is a rotation of B.

Firstly, I would like to ask if the result is correct (I actually carried out the complete proof but thought it would be quite tedious to write it down here). Secondly, I would like to ask if this result holds for finite dimensional vector spaces of arbitrary dimension.

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect.  You could have a reflection, for example, which is not a rotation.

Comment: Wouldn't that change only the order of the elements in basis, which is arbitrary?

Comment: No.  Consider [ -1 0, 0, 1 ], the identity matrix where the first 1 is negated.  This is a reflection, but not a rotation.  And it doesn’t just change the order.

Comment: I see that the matrix is not a rotation, but you could still get the same effect by applying a rotation to the canonical basis, in this case a rotation of π/2, and would be considered a rotation based on the definition I gave, or wouldn't it?

Comment: No.  Look at what happens to the points (1,1) and (1,-1).  With reflection, they become (-1,1) and (-1,-1).  With a rotation of pi/2, they become (-1,1) and (1,-1).

Comment: I see that's the case, however I still can't figure out how that would refute the argument I proposed.

Comment: “The set of orthonormal based or R^2 equals the set of rotations of the canonical basis.“. This statement is incorrect; I’ve provided a counter example in my previous comments.

Comment: I see where the mistake is supposed to be, but what i don't understand is why does that work as a counter example. In the first place because that basis in not normal and in the second place because i'm not saying that rotations and reflections are the same but that a reflection in this case can be reached with a rotation, as in the definition given above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  A reflection is not a rotation; a reflection cannot be reached with a rotation.  When a reflection is applied to the (1,1), (1,-1) basis, you do not get the same vectors as when you rotate those vectors with pi/2.  The quote I provided is incorrect based on the counter example that I provided.  I'm not sure what else to say.  If you're still confused, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how the example would refute the statement I'm proposing above. Let me restate the assertion:

Let {v,u} be a subset of R^2 such that ||v||=||u||=1 and <v,u>=0, being these the norm and the standard dot product in R^2, then there exists a real value "a" such that v=R(a)e_1 and u=R(a)e_2, being {e_1, e_2} the canonical basis of R^2.

As long as I understand this statement is false, the problem is that I don't see how the counter example would apply to it. If I still don't get it, nevermindThank you so much for the patience!!

Comment: Let v = (1,0) and u = (0,-1).  What a would work?

Comment: Take a=3pi/2 then v=R(a)e_2 and u=R(a)e_1 (taking the vectors as column vectors)

Comment: The order of the elements, v and u, is not relevant. That's why I talk about a set {u,v} and not an ordered pair (u,v). The set in this case would be {(1,0), (0,-1)}, regardless of the order of the elements. At least this is what I was trying to define as a rotation, is there something you believe I should include in the definition for it to be clear?  Thank you!

Comment: That is not a rotation.  Changing the order is a permutation.  So you can represent it as a rotation with a permutation, and that is a reflection.

Comment: So, going back to the original post, using the definition I gave but calling it rotation, reflection, symmetry or whatever you want to call it, would there still be any problems in the argument?

Comment: Math is precise, necessarily so.  So “whatever you want to call it” is not a mathematical statement; you must be precise with what you mean.  The proper statement would be “Let U and V be orthogonal matrices.  Then there exists P and R such that U = R P V, where P is a permutation and R is a rotation.”  The columns of U and V are the bases.  By the way, you’re nearing an important theorem which is, “If U is orthogonal, then then norm of Ux equals the norm of x for any vector x.”  Said differently,”Orthogonal matrices preserve norms.”